# Need a way to communicate to Unix machine using WPF application

Tags: wpf, unix

I am creating an application in Windows OS using WPF (C# as code behind) with the data stored in the Unix machine which is in the same network. My app needs a way to communicate with the Unix machine to get the data from it and show it on windows UI (created in WPF).

My app will also need to know all the Unix machines connected in the network via broadcasting.

What is the best way to connect to Unix machines with my WPF application for the above mentioned requirements?

Comment: How is the data accessed? Is it in a database? File share? FTP/HTTP? Custom TCP protocol? Or are you asking which of database/fileshare/ftp/http/custom is the best way to get data from a UNIX box? So far this question is very vague.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the data you want to use is file based, you could use an ftp or samba servers on unix. One of the advantages of samba server is that it has an ability to broadcast and allows discovering of its resources in the network through netbios. This will comply with your broadcasting requirement.

If file based storage is not enough, consider a web service. Since you are writing an application in .NET it will be easiest for you to use Mono on the Unix side. You can write a web service in Mono http://www.mono-project.com/Writing_a_WebService that will listen to requests from your WPF application.

I admit that this solution is not the best in terms of performance, scalability and portability, but it's the quickest for a .net developer.

The other requirement concerning that your app needs to know the list of unix machines is more complicated. Brute force approach would be to have a master server that will listen for notifications from unix machines when they come to life. It will give that list to the WPF client.

If you want to go for a more performing, portable solution and you have more development resources, you can implement a restful service on the unix side with one of these frameworks [REST frameworks](http://code.google.com/p/implementing-rest/wiki/ByLanguage)

The most complex approach in terms of development time is to use bare TCP ip. That will require a lot of coding on both client and server sides and a long process of making it stable. Again it depends on how complex your data interaction is going to be.

Answer (score 0):

"with the data stored in the Unix machine which is in the same network" assuming you mean it is in a database I would recommend some sort of ORM (like NHibernate)

Comment: Basarat Ali - Yes, it's like a database (because it stores data) but not exactly that. It's like getting data from it via FTP or Socket etc...

Comment: which one is it. Is it telnet/straight up tcp(what you called socket)/ftp/http?

Comment: It can be ftp or any other way to communicate.. I just want to know what is the best way to communicate??

Comment: What is the format of the input data? csv Files? Xml Files? excel files?